# How to handle a thread which might not terminate when requested?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

Let's say my class runs up a thread in its constructor, to do background processing, and wants to kill that thread in the destructor.

We would normally set some flag so the thread-main knows it should exit, and then call `thread::join`. But what if the thread is busy doing some long operation - or even stuck (let's say it's blocked waiting on something) - `join` will *never* return?

There's no way to pass a timeout parameter to `join` and no `terminate` method on `std::thread` I can see (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

I'm aware that in a well designed program this shouldn't be allowed to happen but...

Comment: I believe the custom is to use a [future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and wait for a specified time, before deciding that the join failed and setting a flag so the rest of the program knows. [This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223119/is-it-a-good-idea-to-shut-down-a-classs-thread-member-in-the-classs-destructor) may also be of interest to you.

Comment: The thread should exit cleanly regardless of who want to terminate it.  I think to the nice way to do this is to somehow have call make the thread to receive throw an exception and have the thread catch it, but I don't remember the most generic way to do this.  Anyway since you're also the writer of the thread you can make the code that handle the stuck/too long case in the thread itself rather than the caller, and return with an error status.  Or as jaggedSpire suggested, using a `future`.

Comment: @jaggedSpire that's an interesting discussion although it simply seems - after a lot of thought - to do what I propose. The case where `join` hangs doesn't seem to be handled. It seems very strange `thread` has _no_ way to be killed to me though.

Comment: I wonder if calling `detach` is preferable to `join`? But I doubt it!

Comment: You are essentially asking "how to handle a found bug in my program"? The standard way is to be slap the user in the face with a message box, which contains mysterious hex numbers, then have the program halt & catch fire.

Comment: @Lundin lol except if `join` hangs you can't even do that because you're stuck. Unless another thread is spawned to see if killing the first one worked ok .... !

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard facility to forcefully kill a thread. The options are:

- `detach` and let it run on its own forever (till the program exits).
- Use `thread::native_handle()` member to get an underlying handle. Then use you platform library (pthread, or WinAPI or whatever else) to kill the thread.

As of how to detect such a situation, you can use, for example, two `atomic<bool>` variables, `stop` and `finished`. Setting the first, you will instruct the thread to stop. The thread will check this variable periodically and if set, will stop its activities, then set `finished` and exit. Your main program will wait for some time (maybe in a loop) for `finished` to be set, and if so, call `join`. If not, (meaning the thread is not responding), use one of the two solutions above.