# Force program termination if threads block in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

When a class is responsible for managing a thread, it is a common pattern ([see for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11269932/2487023)) to join this thread in the destructor after you have made sure that the thread will finish in time. However, this is not always trivial as outlined in the linked thread leading to a program that never terminates if done incorrectly. Given below is an example to reproduce such a situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        mythread = std::thread([&](){
        int i = 0;
            while(running) {
                std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
                if (i++ >= 2) {
                    // placeholder for e.g. a blocking condition variable
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000h);
                }
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
            }
        });
    }

    ~Foo() {
        running = false;
        mythread.join();
    }

private:
    std::thread mythread;
    bool running{true};
};

int main() {
    Foo bar;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    // enabling this line will block the termination
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);

    std::cout << "ending" << std::endl;
}
```

What I am searching for is a solution that forcefully terminates the program if this situation occurs. Of course, one should always strive towards finishing the thread properly, but having such feature would be good as last resort to have a peace of mind, especially for unobserved embedded systems where crashing programs can be easier restored and debugged than blocking programs.

A rough solution draft would be to start a thread at the end of the main that sleeps for a few seconds and if the program has not ended after that time, std::terminate is called (and ideally a corresponding error is reported). However, we have a chicken-or-egg problem because this new thread will of course keep the program from ending in time. I would highly appreciate any ideas.

**EDIT:** The solution should not require modification of the Foo class itself so that it also covers respective bugs in unmodified code of e.g. external libraries. Ideally, it would even cover threads no class feels responsible for ending them before the main ends (classes with static storage duration or even no longer referenced objects with dynamic storage duration), but that might not be possible at all without in-depth OS hacking or an external process monitor.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

- Investigate and fix the root problem (this is the best and **correct** solution)

Workarounds:

- You can notify from thread about exiting via condition variable. And only after it do `join`. If CV's `wait_for` returns with timeout - kill thread (bad solution, there are another problems).
- You can create watch-thread, which will verify time-counter. Counter should be reset from time to time by the application. If watch-thread detects too high value in time-counter, it restarts whole the application.
- Move suspicious code out of your application to separate process and communicate with it via IPC. In case of problems - restart that application (best among the workarounds)

Comment: That is a good idea (+1) and I am thinking about applying this approach for all threads under my control. However, I am looking for a more general approach since I would also like to cover respective bugs in external libraries that I use (without searching for all thread usages in the external library and applying this approach individually).

Comment: Regarding EDIT 1: That sounds reasonable and can even be extended to a more general solution by wrapping the whole content of the main in this this extra thread. See my approach of this idea: https://gist.github.com/koalo/d1b9118cc207e218685fbf6069c979b9 (feel free to add it to your answer unmodified or modified if you like). Is that similar to what you thought about? The only drawback is that it does not cover classes with static storage duration that are destructed after the main has finished, but that might not be possible at all without in-depth OS hacking.

Comment: Regarding EDIT 2: That might work as well, but is also tricky in this situation, because you need to make sure that the watchdog thread itself is not blocking the destruction of the other classes as in my initial idea.

Comment: I hope I understand what you mean by a watchdog and have implemented it like this https://gist.github.com/koalo/180865d4290d62de602bb3d458c398b3 However, it also does not cover static storage duration just as the other solution (regardless of detaching the watchdog thread or finishing and joining it).

Comment: If app is restarted - static is also freed (only memory, but no calling destructors). In anyway, if you have forever blocked call -- your objects will never be released in terms of OOP (in C++ as well). Objects created on stack in blocked thread will not be destructed. In static memory as well, because whole app hangs, because it should wait for thread termination. This problem is out of OOP. So, you should choose: correctly design app in terms of OOP or don't try to apply OOP/RAII for resolving such problems.

Comment: The best mitigation technique for crashing/blocking 3rd-party libs is -- separate remote process, which is allowed to be crashed or killed and controlled via IPC. (Still are some OOP conflicts).

Comment: Also you can try to use Object Pool for handling objects destruction in such situations

Comment: "static is also freed (only memory, but no calling destructors)": Are you sure? With the following code "destructor" is printed https://gist.github.com/koalo/c6485c1ad799313a4683c39046648a05 and thus the destructor of a static object is also able to block the termination after the main has ended https://gist.github.com/koalo/f5b5b332fc86401c5c7cbcb1b6c80308

Comment: "static is also freed (only memory, but no calling destructors)" -- I mean if app is killed. Seems I understand the question now. Well, I would like to advice you to avoid using static, it's bad practice, because you can't control order of destruction of static objects. Try using singleton with controlled lifetime, which is shorter, than `main` function. Also you can try to use objects's pool and release it in `main` before finish. And after it release your watch thread.

Comment: Yes, my question is a cruel one, because it is basically "given arbitrarily bad code that I can not modify, how can I make sure it does not trash the whole system" ;-) And you are correct that it is probably the best idea to control it from an external process instead of trying to fiddle out all the things that can go wrong from within the same process ;-)